# Reasons to use/not use a centralised DB

Tags: database-design

We have a large ERP style central system and we're looking at moving many small Access databases into it's rather inflexible structure. In most instance the data can be stored but the process is tortuous, breaks the existing data model and makes the system harder to use. Can anyone point me to good resources to explain the pros and cons of this 'centralised all in one DB' approach.

EDIT -> when I say inflexible structure what I mean is we cannot change the schema, and therefore have to store data in ledgers. I get the benefits of the centralised approach from an admin perspective - I'm the DBA trust me I know the hassles of out of control Access. However, I'm not keen on breaking all the tenants of DB design and making it hard for our users just to make sure I can run a backup more easily.

Comment: So you're consolidating a bunch of adhoc Access databases into one system that is centrally maintained, backed-up, and managed?  There are no downsides (other than the initial pain).

Comment: "Can't change the schema" would seem like a pretty big downside.

Answer (score 2):

Choose between being forced to cram your data into an arbitrary schema unrelated to your requirements, and having uncontrolled Access databases floating around? Wow, what a choice, rather in the category of "would you prefer to have someone cut off your fingers, or to rip off your ears?"

Personally, with that choice, I think I'd prefer the uncontrolled Access database. (Wow, I never thought I would use the words "prefer" and "Access" in the same sentence!) Important as all the advantages of a centrally managed database are, having a rational schema is almost certainly more important.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's going to be difficult to find a good reason not to centralize your data access.

Any database technical source will help you see the benefits - especially when it comes to administration.  The main downside will be reworking your current data access to using the new structure.  This may be quite involved.

The benefits are huge, though - including:

- Better scalability
- Maintainability
- Centralized management
- Centralized backups
- Ability to add meaningful security policies

Comment: Two points, 1) Access front end over Sql Server addresses many of these issues, especially with <5 user DBs

2) Breaking existing schemas is a big downside for everyone, in order to get an admin/management gain

Comment: @MrTelly: 1) yes.  You can use access over SQL Server to avoid some of this, although you still have some of the access related issues.  2) It's also a developer gain - some of the issues aren't purely administrative (although most are), such as perf./scalability and security issues, which may be administrative, but also development oriented.

Comment: Ok so we're on the same page - any resources that support centralised/decentralised?